# Hive CSV Import Limit

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a large csv file with about 3.3 million rows that I have uploaded to Hive metastore and created a table from.

However when I run a

select count(*) from table

query on it, it only shows about 1.7 million rows.

I've run a

select * from table

query and downloaded the results as a csv, the file only has about 1.7 million rows in it.

Is there a size limit on a csv file that you can import into hive and create a table from?

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating the Hive table? Is it through the Hive command line interface or HUE? I have seen some limitations with importing or exporting data from the Hive Metastore with HUE so that is one possibility. Also, did you try viewing the job in the JobHistory or any log files?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check your file again, the scenario you are saying may occur for many conditions:

1.) You don't have that many records in file.

2.) Some of your rows are not separated by **new line**, that means records are getting merged. Thats why you are getting less records.

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: Hi Mukesh, thank you for getting back to me.  As a work around I uploaded several smaller 1.5 million row chunks, created tables, and unioned them together in a query, then created a table from the results of the query.  The final table created from the query results had the correct number of rows.  I'm opened the file in sql server and in notepad++.  It shows the correct number of rows in each case.  Any idea what's going on?